# Limitar input text que recebe uma data

Tags: php, html, formulário, input

Estou com um problema onde tenho um campo text em que eu recebo uma data. Porem preciso limitar os dígitos dos dias, meses e ano, por exemplo 31/12/2019, preciso que a pessoa não consiga digitar acima de 31 no dia, nem acima de 12 nos meses e nem acima do ano corrente. Atualmente é possível digitar datas invalidas como 33/33/3333.

Obs: o campo text possui um mask para a data

```
<script>$(function(){
    $("#data").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Comment: Acredito que a melhor maneira para se mecher com data é usando um plugin de Calendar... Vou te mandar um link de um exemplo: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Ou então, tente ir no onValidation do form e lá vc da um split no input de data no '/', com isso vc tem separado o dia,mes, ano e então vc pode tratar isso da maneira que quiser

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o seguinte no seu input no HTML:

```
  <form>
  Nome do input:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
</form>
```

Você pode ver um exemplo aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Answer (score 0):

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^((((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))\x2F(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|([1-9]))\x2F(([0-9]{2})|(((19)|([2]([0]{1})))([0-9]{2}))))$");
        if (reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        {
            //Código caso seja 30/3/2019 (exemplo)
        }
        else
        {
            //Código caso seja 33/33/3333 (exemplo)
        }
```